# Coroutines Flow with Dao and generic Result class

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a Dao class which returns List of Car objects as flow.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Car")
fun getAllCars(): Flow<List<Car>>
```

In my repository, I can use this Dao as follows

```
fun getAllCars(): Flow<List<Car>>
```

```
//Implementation
override fun getAllCars() = carDao.getAllCars()
```

I can observe this `flow` in view model and everything works and life was fine.

Now, after reading the post on [Developer Android site](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum) about

**A generic class that contains data and status about loading this data.**

I got inspired, so I read one more post [here](https://proandroiddev.com/the-real-repository-pattern-in-android-efba8662b754) which discuss about having Result class.

So, I have done some changes to repository and I am not able to solve them.

**Error:**

```
suspend fun getSomeData(): Flow<Result<List<Car>>> {
        carDao.getAllCars().collect {
            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                return flowOf(Result.Success(it))  //<-- Here I am getting error from IDE
            }
            else {
                val throwable = Throwable()
                return flowOf(Result.Failure<List<Car>>(throwable)) //<-- Here I am getting error from IDE
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is `Return is not allowed here` and `Change to 'return@Collect'`

What I want to achieve is:

```
// At view model side
viewmodelScope.launch {

    repo.getSomeData().collect {
      if (it == Result.Success) {
        //Show data
      }
      else {
        //Show empty screen
      }

    }
}
```

Is my approach of implementation of Result is wrong? I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Why I can't just return Flow from a flow

Comment: What's the point of returning `Flow<List<Car>>` instead of `Flow<Car>`?

Comment: I want to fetch all the rows when the data is changed in the table.

Comment: So you will be receiving a continuous stream of `List<Car>`? And every time you'll update the screen with the contents of the latest list? Because that's not at all how you current `getSomeData()` looks like, it returns just a single list wrapped in a flow. If it's a single result, then why use flow and not `Deferred` or something like that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik because I want to observe stream of data. Where deferred don't provide me that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your function should look like. Note there's no need for it to be a `suspend fun`.

```
fun getSomeData(): Flow<Result<List<Car>>> = flow {
    carDao.getAllCars().collect {
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            emit(Result.Success(it))
        }
        else {
            emit(Result.Failure<List<Car>>(Throwable()))
        }
    }
}
```

But what it does is nothing more than adding a mapping step, which you can generalize.

```
fun <T> Flow<List<T>>.toResultFlow(): Flow<Result<List<T>>> = this.map {
    if (it.isNotEmpty()) Result.Success(it)
    else Result.Failure(Throwable())
}
```

Comment: thanks. But do you think this approach is right? If not then would you like to suggest better option.

Comment: I don't know what you intend to throw instead of that `Throwable()`. If you don't have an actual error to report, then this whole thing isn't any improvement on just a flow of lists. If there is an actual exception, then something like `toResultFlow` seems good.

Comment: I am trying to return formatted output for my actual output. If there success, I want to return the success status and if it is error, I want to pass error. Please see the `Resource` class on this site: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum

Comment: So in actual code you wouldn't detect an error simply by the list being empty, you'd actually get some exception from `getAllCars()`? But it returns a `Flow` of lists and not just one result. I'm afraid I still don't follow exactly how you intend to get and propagate errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Result, you should should return Result < YourClass>. It will look like that :

```
        suspend fun getSomeData(): Result<Flow<List<Car>>> {
            return  carDao.getAllCars().collect {
                if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                   Result.Success(flowOf(it)) 
                } else {
                   Result.Failure(Throwable())) 
                }
             }
        }
```

Comment: Tried, not working. 1. let operator is not allowing me to verify empty. 2. Even If I got ride of the empty check, it is forcing me to return `Unit` type which is contradictory.

Comment: You are right. You will have to use collect, I updated the example.